# Limit of a function to the power of another function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there a theorem in real analysis for $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim f(n)^{g(n)}$, where $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are arbitrary functions of $n$? Under what conditions on $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ does the limit exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not going to be any "nice" condition. You certainly have that the function $A(x,y)=x^y$ is continuous on the half-plane $x\geq 0$ (which is the domain you would typically use it on), except at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, which means that if the limits $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(n)$ exist in this domain and are not both zero, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)^{g(n)}=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)\right)^{\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(n)\right)}$$

Otherwise, there's no clear method for determining convergence, since $f$ and $g$ could be as ill-behaved as we desire. However, it can be helpful to write $f(n)^{g(n)}$ as $\exp(g(n)\log(f(n)))$ where $\exp(x)=e^x$ and then to try to find what the product $g(n)\log(f(n))$ is doing via other techniques. (L'Hopital's rule can be useful here)

Comment: So which theorem do you use to claim that ``If $f(n)^{g(n)}$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)$ exist and both are not equal to zero, then we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)^{g(n)}=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\right)^{\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)\right)}$" ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's got a name; it's only saying that if $A$ is continuous and so is $P$, then so is their composition $A\circ P$ - here $A$ is the exponentiation function and $P$ is the pair $(f,g)$. You could prove that exponentiation is continuous through typical $\varepsilon-\delta$ methods. It's been addressed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386925/why-is-real-exponentiation-continuous-in-the-base) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223829/showing-the-exponential-function-is-continuous).

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to write $h(n)=\frac{1}{g(n)}$ and write:

$$f(n)^{g(n)} = \exp\left({\frac{\log f(n)}{h(n)}}\right)$$

So you need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log f(n)}{h(n)}$ which, when $f(n)\to 0$ and $h(n)\to 0$, or $f(n)\to\infty, h(n)\to\infty$ will then require L'Hopital or something else.

If $f(n)\to 1$ and $g(n)\to\infty$, you can write $f_1(n)=g(n)(f(n)-1)$. If $f_1(n)\to \alpha$ then $f(n)^{g(n)}\to e^\alpha$.

Comment: Does it hold, for any function $\phi(n)$, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(\phi(n))=\exp(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\phi(n))$?

Comment: Yes, because $\exp$ is a continuous function. (So only when $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(n)$ exists.) If $\phi(n)\to+\infty$ then $\exp(\phi(n))\to \infty$. If $\phi(n)\to -\infty$ then $\exp(\phi(n))\to 0$ and, if $\phi(n)$ otherwise diverges, then $\exp(\phi(n))$ diverges.

Comment: What if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(n)\rightarrow \infty$ (which means $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{h(n)}\rightarrow 0$) and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log f(n)\rightarrow 0$? Do I still need to apply L'hopital rule?

Comment: $g(n)\to\infty$ means $h(n)\to 0$, not $1/h(n)\to 0$. In that case, you'll need to work it out, possibly using L'Hopital.

Comment: If $f(n)\to 1$ and $g(n)\to\infty$, you can write $f_1(n)=g(n)(f(n)-1)$. If $f_1(n)\to \alpha$ then $f(n)^{g(n)}\to e^\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write
$f(n)^{g(n)}
=e^{g(n)\ln f(n)}
$,
you only need exp, ln, and multiplication.